# Should I add the reverse proxy in the same container as the application on docker?

Tags: django, nginx, docker

I would like to setup a Django environment in a docker container. Should I add the reverse proxy (nginx) in the same container as the Django app or should I have two containers?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, as illustrated in "[Django Development With Docker Compose and Machine](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/) ", you should have one container per service:

> - 1 web/Django container
> - 1 nginx container
> - 1 Postgres container
> - 1 Redis container
> - 1 data container

[image: https://realpython.com/images/blog_images/dockerizing-django/container-stack.png].

For the proxy part, [Thomasleveil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107049/thomasleveil) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695018/should-i-add-the-reverse-proxy-in-the-same-container-as-the-application-on-docke/31695261#comment51333859_31695261) [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), with `docker-gen`, which generates reverse proxy configs for nginx and reloads nginx when containers are started and stopped.

In practice, you can start training with just one container in order to test things out, as in [dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx](https://github.com/dockerfiles/django-uwsgi-nginx).

Comment: see [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) for an easy to setup reverse proxy container

Comment: @Thomasleveil good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.